# Linear Layout inside Frame Layout stops working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-framelayout

My Layout is working fine, It has a parent `Linear Layout` and multiple `Linear Layouts` inside it.

Now i need to add a background image,So that i need to add a frame layout here.

When i change parent `Linear Layout` to `Frame Layout`, it disappears all the items in the `linear layout`.

If i add `Frame Layout`,inside `Linear Layout` it disappears all the items in the Linear layout.

I am unable to understand how to put a frame layout without removing Linear Layout items.

The Layout code is quite long.

I am putting above part of it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:src="@drawable/image11"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"

                >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="7:00 PM CST"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:src="@drawable/icon2"
            />

    </LinearLayout>





    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/cart_custom_background"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                >
```

Comment: Try Relative Layout instead of Frame Layout

Comment: Thanks @Dnyanesh, when i change `parent layout` to `Relative Layout`, All the elements disappears

Comment: Are you sure about your layout_height / layout_width are not equal to 0 dp inside the framelayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i need to add a background image,So that i need to add a frame
>   layout here.

You don't need to add another layout to give background. Your root (or even any other)`<LinearLayout>` should be enough. You can set the background using:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_drawable" > // Can also give color here
```

> When i change parent Linear Layout to Frame Layout, it disappears all
>   the items in the linear layout.

Thats primarily because the `<FrameLayout>` unlike `<LinearLayout>` kept adding all the children on top of each other.